# Python tablecheck error

Tags: python

```
def tableCheck(elev, n, m): 
   tablePosCount = 0
   rowPosCount = 0

   for r in range(1, n):
      for c in range(1, m): 
         if elev[r][c] > 0:       
            tablePosCount = tablePosCount + 1
            rowPosCount = rowPosCount + 1
            print 'Number of positive entries in row ', r , ' : ', rowPosCount
   print 'Number of positive entries in table :', tablePosCount
   return tablePosCount
elev = [[1,0,-1,-3,2], [0,0,1,-4,-1], [-2,2,8,1,1]]
tableCheck(elev, 3, 5)
```

I'm having some difficulty getting this code to run properly. If anyone can tell me why it might being giving me this output

```
Number of positive entries in row  1  :  1
Number of positive entries in row  2  :  2
Number of positive entries in row  2  :  3
Number of positive entries in row  2  :  4
Number of positive entries in row  2  :  5
Number of positive entries in table : 5
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three things in your code that I suspect are errors, though since you don't describe the behavior you expect, it's possible that one or more of these is working as intended.

The first issue is that you print out the "row" number every time that you see a new value that is greater than 0. You probably want to unindent the `print 'Number of positive entries in row '` line by two levels (to be even with the inner `for` loop).

The second issue is that you don't reset the count for each row, so the print statement I suggested you move will not give the right output after the first row. You probably want to move the `rowPosCount = 0` line inside the outer loop.

The final issue is that you're skipping the first row and the first value of each later row. This is because your `range`s go from `1` to `n` or `m`. Python indexing starts at 0, and ranges exclude their upper bound. You probably want `for r in range(n)` and `for c in range(m)`, though iterating on the table values themselves (or an enumeration of them) would be more Pythonic.